# Jquery Ajax method not calling codebehind asp.net method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#frmReg").on('submit', function (e) {
var emailAddr = $("#inputEmail").val();
            var userName = $("#userName").val();
            var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
            var FormData = {
                Email: emailAddr,
                UserName: userName,
                Password: password
            };
            var dd = JSON.stringify(FormData);
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Register.aspx/EmailAvailability",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"formData":'+ dd+ ' }',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Entered");
                    },
                    fail: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ajax CodeBehind file:
This is Asp.net method.

```
public static bool EmailAvailability(string formData)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you check browser console for any errors?

Comment: If my answer helped you mark it as correct !

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here. **You already make the dd looks like Json, with JSON.stringify !**

```
data: '{"formData":'+ dd+ ' }',
```

This should look like:

```
data: dd,
```

And your dd object can be done like this, if you want to be an array of items:

```
var uData = [];
uData[0] = emailAddr;
uData[1] = userName;
uData[2] = password;

var dd = JSON.stringify(uData: uData);
```

Now your web service method will look like 
`EmailAvailability(List<string> uData)`

If you want them as separate parameters:

```
 var dd = JSON.stringify(emailAddr: emailAddr, userName: userName, password: password);
```

And in this case your web service method will look like `EmailAvailability(string emailAddr, string userName, string password)`

Don't forget that `data: dd` !

**P.S: I also don't see the attribute `[WebMethod]` in the code behind in your example don't forget it !**

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static bool EmailAvailability(string formData)
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: The suggestion to change to `data: dd,` I don't think will help here - as the method is expecting a string, not an object (or multiple parameters). Though, you're right - it's better practice to do as you suggested, but he also needs to update the C# method to no longer take just a string parameter.

Comment: @Rob because of that I wrote how his EmailAvaiability will look like in this two cases, you ca read it !